# Could I know what has been changed lately in the file?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm doing some development and my company does use excel to edit database (I don't agree but, hey... hate the game, not the player! :D ). So, to avoid some encoding problems, I aiming to put it to Google Drive because it's very unlikely to change this sort of things the Microsoft insists in change every d**m version.

What I'm trying to do is: receive a file from Google Drive with only the fields that has been lately manipulated (or even receive the entire file, but somehow I could know the last changes), put it on a variable and manipulate it. I don't have the need to edit de excel file itself. It's going to be on Google Drive's interface. I only need to read it.

**NOTE 1:** I was using this doc (https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-changes) , but it appears that the API only says if either the file has been changed or not. I would be very nice if I could know what has been changed in the file. It would avoid me a overload in the database (I'll have to re-write the ENTIRE DATABASE).

Comment: +1 beacause of the "hate the game, not the player! :D"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to retrieve field changes, but you can retrieve a change history by listing changes.
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to check [Revision](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/list).

Google Drive provides file revision and you can get list of changes using this API